# Simple Injector - RegisterAll registration injects empty collection in constructor

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have the following factory:

```cs
public class MyFactory : IMyFactory
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IMyService> myServices

    public MyFactory(IEnumerable<IMyService> myServices)
    {   
        this.myServices = myServices;
    }
}
```

I am registering my `IEnumerable<IMyService>` like this:

```cs
container.Register<IMyFactory, MyFactory>();

container.RegisterAll<IMyService>(
    from s in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    from type in s.GetExportedTypes()
    where !type.IsAbstract
    where typeof(IMyService).IsAssignableFrom(type)
    select type);

container.Verify();
```

Then I get the following results

```cs
// correctly resolves to count of my 4 implementations 
// of IMyService
var myServices = container.GetAllInstances<IMyService>();

// incorrectly resolves IEnumerable<IMyService> to count 
// of 0 IMyServices.
var myFactory = container.GetInstance<IMyFactory>();
```

Why is it that my factory cannot resolve the collection of services?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your configuration. The problem might be elsewhere. Try setting a break point inside `MyFactory`'s constructor and inspect the injected enumerable. It will probably have four elements. If not, there might be something in your configuration that you haven't shown, but that is screwing things up.

Comment: injected enumerable is definately 0 elements. my registration is  container.Register<IMyFactory, MyFactory>(); container.Register<IMyManager, MyManager>(); - (takes an IMyFactory as  dependency.) container.RegisterAll<IMyService>(
                from nd in AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                                     .GetAssemblies()
                from type in nd.GetExportedTypes()
                where !type.IsAbstract
                where typeof (IMyService).IsAssignableFrom(type)
                select type); then all i do is - var myManager = container.GetInstance<IMyManager>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the following console application:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using SimpleInjector;

public interface IMyManager { }
public interface IMyFactory { }
public interface IMyService { }

public class MyManager : IMyManager
{
    public MyManager(IMyFactory factory) { }
}

public class MyFactory : IMyFactory
{
    public MyFactory(
        IEnumerable<IMyService> services)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyFactory(Count: {0})",
            services.Count());
    }
}

public class Service1 : IMyService { }
public class Service2 : IMyService { }
public class Service3 : IMyService { }
public class Service4 : IMyService { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new Container();

        container.Register<IMyFactory, MyFactory>(); 
        container.Register<IMyManager, MyManager>(); 

        container.RegisterAll<IMyService>(
            from nd in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            from type in nd.GetExportedTypes()
            where !type.IsAbstract 
            where typeof(IMyService).IsAssignableFrom(type) 
            select type); 

        var myManager = container.GetInstance<IMyManager>();

        Console.WriteLine("IMyService count: " + 
            container.GetAllInstances<IMyService>().Count());
    }
}
```

When I run it, it outputs the following:

> MyFactory(Count: 4)
>   IMyService count: 4

Comment: Thanks Steven. Actually I am happy with that test as it is what is happening for me!  However, when I use myManager.DoSomething() and step into the injected factory - there are 0 IMyServices injected.

Comment: @jonho: You will have present some code that allows me to reproduce the issue. Is this only happening during debugging?

Comment: Yes, when I ask my factory for a Service there are none in the list. will send some code over this morning.

Comment: steven you were absolutely right, it was the correct setup. I had a typo I was injecting an IEnumerable<MyService> to my factory. but I actually registering an IMyService in my container  container.RegisterAll<IMyService>(....  It works like a dream now.

Comment: Most containers allow you to inject a collection of things that you haven't registered explicitly by injecting an empty collection for you; Simple Injector is no exception. Although it can be very convenient, it can also be a pain in the ass, as you just witnessed. You could add an extra `ResolveUnregisteredType` event to the container to prevent unregistered collections from being resolved automatically.